# open tor browser with python using selenium package

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, tor

I am trying to scrape websites from tor browser.
I have done it with this code :

```
import webbrowser
url = 'http://www.google.com/'
webbrowser.register('firefox', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(r"C:\Users\Lenovo\Bureau\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe"))
webbrowser.get('firefox').open(url)
```

but I'm actually more familiar with selenium library when it comes to web scraping.
I tried with this code but a **WebDriverException** error is raised.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
binary = FirefoxBinary("C:/Users/Lenovo/Bureau/Tor Browser/Browser/firefox.exe")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary = binary)
url = 'https://www.google.com/'
driver.get(url)
```

i wonder what causes this error and how can i solve it.

Here is the full error i encountered:

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17288/4279882525.py in <module>
      1 url = 'https://www.google.com/'
----> 2 driver.get(url)

~\anaconda3\envs\aa\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in get(self, url)
    434         Loads a web page in the current browser session.
    435         """
--> 436         self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
    437 
    438     @property

~\anaconda3\envs\aa\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    422         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    423         if response:
--> 424             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    425             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    426                 response.get('value', None))

~\anaconda3\envs\aa\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    245                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    246             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 247         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    248 
    249     def _value_or_default(self, obj: Mapping[_KT, _VT], key: _KT, default: _VT) -> _VT:

WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=proxyConnectFailure&u=https%3A//www.google.com/&c=UTF-8&d=Firefox%20is%20configured%20to%20use%20a%20proxy%20server%20that%20is%20refusing%20connections.
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:181:5
UnknownError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:488:5
checkReadyState@chrome://remote/content/marionette/navigate.js:64:24
onNavigation@chrome://remote/content/marionette/navigate.js:312:39
emit@resource://gre/modules/EventEmitter.jsm:160:20
receiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteEventsParent.jsm:42:25
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: without showing error message question is only waste of time.  I guess `driver` is created for some version of `Firefox` but  `tor` uses different version of `Firefox`. OR maybe `tor` is safe browser because it turns off some functions - but `driver` may need these functions to access browser.

Comment: Maybe you should use `tor` as `proxy-server` in normal `Firefox`. I didn't tested this wth `Selenium` but here is example for `requests` [Python: How to use Tor Network with requests to change IP?](https://blog.furas.pl/python-how-to-use-tor-network-with-requests-to-change-ip.html)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show error message so I don't know what is your problem.

When I try to use `tor` on Linux then it opens `tor` without errors
(only with warning `"firefox_binary has been deprecated"` but this is not problem)
but later it doesn't load page - `get(url)` - and it doesn't show error.
Maybe `tor` is safe browser because it blocks some functions which `Selenium` needs to control browser.

---

But if you run `tor network` then you can use it as `proxy server` with normal `Firefox`.

If page http://127.0.0.1:9050 shows `"This is a SOCKs proxy, not an HTTP proxy."`
then `tor network` is running and you can do:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'socksProxy': '127.0.0.1:9050',
    'socksVersion': 5,
})

options = Options()
options.proxy = proxy 
#options.binary_location = '/home/furas/bin/tor'  # doesn't work
#options.binary_location = '/path/to/normal/firefox'  # works

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)  #  use path to standard `Firefox`

url = 'https://www.google.com/'
url = 'https://icanhazip.com'     # it shows your IP
#url = 'https://httpbin.org/get'  # it shows your IP and headers/cookies

driver.get(url)
```

---

PS. sometimes `tor` may use port `9150` instead of `9050`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did edit my question and I added the full error I encountered in my code. I tried as you said but nothing changed. The same error has already raised.

Comment: I had the same error - problem is that `tor` doesn't allow to run `get()` and it will never run with `Selenium`. I think they tried to make `tor` safe browser and they have to block some functions which `Selenium` need to control browser. `Selenium` normally inject some JavaScript code to control browser but this is not safe.